How can Log Out from User Panel and redirect to Home in ASP.NEt
this is my logout method in user panel .I want to when I log out , it redriect to action Index but in the Other Controller
I mean In Main Controller and "Index" method
    [HttpGet("UserPanel/Exit")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> LogOut()
    {
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        TempData[InfoMessage] = "You Logout SuccessFully";
      
   
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

    }


Is there any error when RedirectToAction?

@QiangFu first I had an Index method in current controller and it goes to that index method. but I change its name and now does not go any where

@QiangFu I add it and it works: )
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "/" });

@QiangFu But I think it s not correct , what is the name of site area? because I need it other place, and I want to tell an action go to that method to site area

I add this code and it works
      [HttpGet("UserPanel/Exit")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> LogOut()
  {
      await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
      TempData[InfoMessage] = "You Logout SuccessFully";
    
 
      return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "/" });

  }

